Dirac delta of operators multiplying matrix element
In playing around with the Wigner-Weyl correspondence, I found myself needing to perform an integral of exponential operators, which I am confused about. TLDR: help to evaluate $$\int d{x}dy\ \delta(x\hat{I}-\hat{Q})\langle x|\hat{A}| y\rangle e^{i(y-x)\hat{P}},$$ how do I perform the delta integration? The answer should be just $\hat{A}$ (an arbitrary operator). Some background to the problem:
The Weyl map associates an operator $\Phi[f]$ to a function on phase space $f$ and is defined by $$\Phi[f]=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int d{\lambda}d{\kappa}\tilde{f}(\lambda,\kappa)e^{i(\lambda \hat{Q}+\kappa\hat{P})},$$
where $\tilde{f}(\lambda,\kappa)$ is the $2$-dimensional Fourier transform of $f(q,p)$ and $\hat{Q}$, $\hat{P}$ are operators of the Heisenberg algebra.
The Wigner transform is the supposed inverse mapping, taking an operator $\hat{A}$ to a function $A(q,p)$ by $$A(q,p)=\int d{x} e^{-ipx}\langle q+\frac{x}{2}|\hat{A}| q-\frac{x}{2}\rangle.$$
I was easily able to show that Wigner transform of $\Phi[f]$ is $f(q,p)$. But now I would like to show that the Weyl transform of $A(q,p)$ is $\hat{A}$, ie $\Phi[A(q,p)]=\hat{A}$. In one of the first steps of the calculation, I need to evaluate $$\int d{\lambda} e^{-i\lambda q}e^{i\lambda \hat{Q}}e^{\frac{i}{2}\lambda\kappa\hat{I}}\langle q-\frac{\kappa}{2}|\hat{A}| q+\frac{\kappa}{2}\rangle=\delta((q-\frac{\kappa}{2})\hat{I}-\hat{Q})\langle q-\frac{\kappa}{2}|\hat{A}| q+\frac{\kappa}{2}\rangle.$$ A change of variables brings it to the form at the start of the question.

The answer you link provides you exactly with what you are looking for. I will state it in a slightly different way which should make it hopefully clearer.
You have the identity
$$
f(y) = \int dx f(x) \delta(x-y) \tag{1}
$$
where $x,y$ are real numbers. Functional calculus is the mathematical theory that allows to compute $f(A)$ if $A$ is an Hermitian operator. Hence just substitute $A$ for $y$ in the above.
For finite dimensional operators, computing $f(A)$ is defined in the following way. Since $A$ is Hermitian it admits the spectral decomposition
$$
A =\sum_n a_n |n\rangle\langle n|
$$
Where $a_n$ and $|n\rangle$ are the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$ respectively.
Then $f(A)$ is defined as
$$
f(A)=\sum_n f(a_n) |n\rangle\langle n| \, . 
$$
With the above definition you can check that the following identity holds:
$$
f(A) = \int dx f(x) \delta(x \mathbb{I} -A) 
$$
Edit 1/5/24
Given the comments I think the following should be useful.
The operator $\Phi[f]$ can be written as an integral operator with a certain kernel $K(x,y) := \langle x| \Phi[f]|y\rangle $ (that you have already defined). The kernel $K$ satisfies a certain equation (see for example here)
Now one has the following two equations (I'm setting $\hbar =1$)
\begin{align*}
K(x,y) & =\int\frac{dp}{2\pi}e^{ip(x-y)}f\left(\frac{x+y}{2},p\right)\\
f(q,p) & =\int dze^{-ipz}K\left(q+\frac{z}{2},q-\frac{z}{2}\right).
\end{align*}
One can indeed check that the above equations are the inverse of each
other. For example
\begin{align*}
K(x,y) & =\int\frac{dp}{2\pi}e^{ip(x-y)}\int dze^{-ipz}K\left(\frac{x+y+z}{2},\frac{x+y-z}{2}\right)\\
 & =\int dz\delta\left(x-y-z\right)K\left(\frac{x+y+z}{2},\frac{x+y-z}{2}\right)\\
 & =K(x,y).
\end{align*}

Yes, I agree with all the above, but in the case $f(x)=\langle x + y| \hat{A} | x - y\rangle$, is there a simplification for $f(x)\delta(x\hat{I}-\hat{B})$, where $B$ is an operator? Ie is there a simplifcation for $f(\hat{B})$ where $f$ is the matrix element I wrote above?

What exactly is the formula you are trying to prove? You are right in saying that $\vert \hat{B} -y \rangle$ doesn't make any sense (unless you define it to be something).

I would like to show that the Weyl transform is the inverse of the Wigner transform. If all things go well, I would like to explicitly show that (up to some normalising constant) $\hat{A}=\int d{\lambda d{\kappa} d{q} e^{-iq\lambda} \langle q-\frac{\kappa}{2}|\hat{A}|q+\frac{\kappa}{2} \rangle e^{i\lambda\hat{q}}e^{i\kappa\hat{p}}}e^{\frac{i}{2}\lambda\kappa \hat{I}}$. So you see the lambda integral is $\int d{\lambda} e^{-i\lambda(q\hat{I}-\hat{q}-\frac{\kappa}{2}\hat{I})}=2\pi\delta(q\hat{I}-\hat{q}-\frac{\kappa}{2}\hat{I})$, which multiplies the matrix element. Does this make sense?

I can simplify it further, Now I'm evaluating $\int d{x} d{y} \delta(x\hat{I}-\hat{q}) <x|\hat{A}|y> e^{i(y-x)\hat{p}}$. Any ideas?

I think the simplest way is to check the inverse for the kernel of the operator $\Phi[f]$ which is $K(x,y):=\langle x|\Phi[f] |y\rangle $. You have an equation for $K$ in terms of $f$ and one for $f$ in terms of $K$. Let me know if it's clear

I added a section that should clarify. Let me know

You may well have taken a dangerous left turn on the bridge and fallen in the abyss of glib ill-defined infinite-dimensional distributions. The straightforward proof of the correct Weyl transform inverting the correct Wigner transform is just a bland plugin and performance of  four integrals. E.g., in my favorite review , plug (138) into (134) in your language, for the Wigner transform, setting ℏ=1,
$$
?= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int \!\! d\kappa d\lambda dq dp dx~ e^{i\kappa (\hat P -p)+i\lambda (\hat Q -q)} e^{-ixp} 
\langle q+x/2|\hat A |q-x/2\rangle .
$$
Now prove and utilize the identity on the eigenstates of ̂,   $$
\exp(\hat P+\hat Q)=\exp((r−/2))\int\!\!  ~~|−⟩⟨|, $$
to convert your integral to
$$
?=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int \!\! d\kappa d\lambda dq dp dx dr~ e^{(r−/2) -i\kappa p-i\lambda q -ixp} |−⟩ 
\langle q+x/2|\hat A |q-x/2\rangle ⟨| \\
=\int \!\! dr dx ~~|x\rangle \langle x |\hat A | r\rangle\langle r| =\hat A.
$$
Performing the p integral first, yields $\delta (\kappa +x)$,
through which you collapse the $\kappa$ integral; performing the $\lambda$ integral, you get $\delta( r -q +x/2)$, through which you collapse the q integral; you finally shift rename x, to get the obvious answer.

Thanks Cosmas, this is excellent. I think the step I was missing was the identity involving $\exp[i\lambda \hat{Q}+i\kappa\hat{P}]$ and the eigenstates of $\hat{Q}$.

To prove it, you reverse CBH, separating the Q and P exponentials, and insert complete sets of eigenstates of Q in between. The action of Q is trivial, but the action of P is the usual translation by κ. It is then straightforward...
